# How to hide "InstanceID Token:" box that my Android app displays when loading

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I started to use Firebase for push notifications and in order to do that, I had to upgrade several Google libraries. Everything works correctly for me now but one thing that I noticed was that when my app loaded, on the first screen it was displaying a box that said `InstanceID Token:` and it displayed a token. I do not want that box and I have not written anything in the code for that box and token to appear. Where does it come from? Is it something that Firebase or maybe a Facebook plugin or another plugin does automatically? How can I remove that? I searched for `System.out.println()` statements and `InstanceID Token:` keywords in my source code, trying to find what could be making that box to appear, but I could not find anything. It was not happening to my app before the upgrades to Firebase for push notifications. Anyone experiencing a similar situation and knowing how to fix it?

Note: It appears for about 2 seconds when the app is loading and then it disappears by itself. See the screenshot below:

[image]

Any hints will be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a Toast displaying the Instance ID. Search for something like `Toast.makeText`.

Comment: `Toast.makeText(...).show();` was causing that text to appear. Thank you very much Mariano!